# Generating N points from polygon field values in FME?

Tags: point, fme-form

I have a polygon layer with 33 rows. I want to generate N number of points at the centroid of each polygon, where N is a value unique to each polygon contained in a field value.

I've been looking at the Creator transformer, but I can't figure out how to feed the Creator with dynamic values for X/Y or the amount of features to create, based on another dataset.

There is a RandomPointGenerator available from the FME Hub, however it seems this transformer cannot create points based on field values, only a fixed, common value for all the polygons in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. You just use the Cloner transfomer and connect that to the appropriate field value. If you want N points at the centroid you can run the polygons through a CenterPointReplacer first.